# Relacionamento através de chave estrangeira no django

Tags: python, django-2.0

Possuo duas tabelas na model Cliente e Animal, onde animal possui uma chave estrangeira para Cliente, consigo listar todos os animais relacionados ao cliente na tabela, mas os cliente que não possuem animais não consigo lista-los, como conseguir listar os cliente sem animais com os que possuem animais na mesma tabela: segue abaixo meu código.

**models**

```
 class Cliente(models.Model):

    codigoCliente = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    rg = models.CharField(max_length=9, null=False, blank=False)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=False, blank=False)
    dataNascimentoCliente = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Data de Nascimento')
    numeroTelefoneFixo = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Telefone Fixo')
    numeroTelefoneCelular = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Telefone Celular')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False, blank=False)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.nome, self.sobrenome)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.nome, self.sobrenome)


class Animal(models.Model):

    codigoAnimal = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False)
    nomeAnimal = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, verbose_name='Nome do Animal')
    dataNascimentoAnimal = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    pelagem = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=PELAGEMCHOICES)
    especie = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    raca = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, verbose_name='Raça')
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SEXOCHOICES)
    deficiencia = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=DEFICIENCIACHOICES)
    descreva = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagens', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Foto do Animal')

    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.nomeAnimal, self.raca)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.nomeAnimal, self.raca)
```

**na views**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def consultaRegistro(request, template_name='consultaRegistro.html'):


    animal = Animal.objects.all()



    return render(request, template_name, {'animal': animal })

**template**

                    {% for a in animal  %}
                    <tr>

                      <td><a href="/consultaDetails/{{ c.cliente_id }}/">{{ a.cliente_id }}</a></td>
                      <td><a href="/consultaDetails/{{ c.cliente_id }}/">{{ a.cliente.nome }}</a></td>
                      <td><a href="/consultaDetails/{{ c.cliente_id }}/">{{ a.nomeAnimal }}</a></td>


                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Se você precisa de todos os clientes, não bastaria fazer `Cliente.objects.all()`?

Comment: sim, já fiz isso só que quando vou varre no template acabo tendo que fazer dois FOR, ai não consigo colocar os registros de animais  os registros de cliente na mesma tabela.